# Is merge sort an adaptive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

We have 3 variants of Merge sort.

1. Top down
2. Bottom up
3. Natural

Are any of these adaptive algorithms? For instance, if an array is sorted they will take advantage of the sorted order.

According to me, no matter if an array is sorted or not, merge sort will still go in for comparisons and then merge. So, the answer is none of these are adaptive.

Is my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Natural merge sort **is** adaptive. For example, it executes only one run through sorted array and makes N comparisons.

Both top down and bottom up sorts are not adaptive, they always make O(NlogN) operations

Comment: Even when an array is sorted, an array will be sub-divided, and the comparison will be made between A[0..n/2] and A[n/2..n-1] through arrays B and C.

Comment: Have you seen description of natural merge sort? Pre-merge phase isolates monotonic series, then merge phase merges them. If whole array is monotonic, there is no need to subdivide and merge.

Answer (score 0):

Merge Sort is an implementation of divide and conquer algorithm. You need to divide the whole array into sub arrays. For example
[1, 3 ,5, 6, 2, 4,1 10] is divided into [1 3 5 6] and [2 4 1 10].  [1 3 5 6] is divided into [1 3] and [5 6]. Now as both [1 3] and [5 6] are sorted swap procedure is not needed.

So there is at least a little complexity if the array is sorted

Comment: in your example, the key comparison is still being made, which is our costliest operation. We are not concerned about swapping over here..

Answer (score 0):

> Accoring to me, no matter if an array is sorted or not, merge sort will still go in for comparisons

I don't think its possible to sort without any comparisons **and save memory** if the input is not already sorted or contains information regarding what sorting procidure to follow. The fastest sorting algorithm is of time complexity O(n log(n)) (there are sorting techniques like bead sorting. I am not considering it here as it is not an optimal method memory vice)

P.S quick sort does involve comparisons (but is adaptive), and in its worse case it makes about O(n^2) comparisons.

P.P.S   Radix sort, counting sort and bucket sort are some examples of adaptive sort;

Comment: Radix sort, counting sort and bucket sort are, in a way, comparison-free sorting algorithms.

Comment: What about Quick sort? Isnt it adaptive?

Comment: by writing this: "I don't think its possible to sort without any comparisons" I had only meant that it wouldn't be optimal to chose an algorithm that requires n^2 units of memory for an operation done on n elements.